# advice regarding security and correct configuration for Nginx reverse Proxy and Radicale caldav server in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, radicale

I'm trying to use docker for an nginx reverse proxy and Radicale caldav server, set up on top of an existing openmediavault server .
I've managed after many hours research to get it working (I think) I use docker compose to create my containers.

I would prefer an experienced user cast an eye over my setup to suggest where I can improve/ better secure  my setup.

I run the reverse nginx proxy container in a network with only the radicale container that way I can run other containers(like jellyfin) with out exposing them also.

My main worry is have I covered all the bases before exposing the radicale server to open ports? I'm using the certbot  --standalone option of receiving the lets encrypt certs and using hooks to stop the container ,check for a renewal and then restart the containers. I've utilised mainly this [guide](https://www.domysee.com/blogposts/reverse-proxy-nginx-docker-compose) to get my setup up and running.

The Radicale server utilises basic authentication but also has its own user authentication to login so I'm not entirely sure how a client logs in twice to sync the calendar.

below is my code so far

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - radicale 
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx_reverse_proxy
    volumes:
      - /home/tim/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - /home/tim/radicale/users:/etc/nginx/users
      - /home/tim/nginx/error.log:/etc/nginx/error_log.log
      - /etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - radicale

  radicale:
    image: tomsquest/docker-radicale
    container_name: radicale
    expose:
      - "5232"
    init: true
    read_only: true
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - SETUID
      - SETGID
      - CHOWN
      - KILL
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -f http://127.0.0.1:5232 || exit 1
      interval: 30s
      retries: 3
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /home/tim/radicale/data:/data
      - /home/tim/radicale/config:/config:ro
    networks:
      - radicale

networks:
  radicale:
```

**nginx.conf**

```
events {

}

http {
  error_log /etc/nginx/error_log.log warn;
  
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name myserver.duckdns.org;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    
  }
  
  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myserver.duckdns.org;

    location /radicale/ {
    proxy_pass           http://radicale:5232/;
    proxy_set_header     X-Script-Name /radicale;
    proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header     X-Remote-User $remote_user;
    auth_basic           "Radicale - Password Required";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/users;

    }
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.duckdns.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.duckdns.org/privkey.pem;
        
    

  }
  
  
}
```

**and my radicale config**

```
[server]
hosts = 0.0.0.0:5232

[storage]
filesystem_folder = /data/collections

[auth]
type =  http_x_remote_user
htpasswd_filename = /etc/nginx/users
htpasswd_encryption = md5
```

I used md5 as the password encryption, although bcrypt is better because bcrypt doesnt work with the debian based image for nginx , so in the future I may use the apline image so I can use the more secure bcrypt.

After Docker-compose up and as soon as I open the ports, I can see that the reverse proxy works and I can login albeit twice to the Radicale server and all http traffic is diverted back to https but as expected I instantly get interest from malicious IP's, so to be certain I want to make sure I dotted all the i's and crossed all the t's as practically as possible,  before I let the exposed server loose.

is there any improvements I can make? is my setup correct?

thanks in advance .